# Testing methods that use common internal property

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I need to test 2 methods that use common protected property. The first method allows to set PDO instance, second one uses the instance to select some data from the database, so I have to test them one by one.

```
class SomeClass {

  protected $db; // PDO instance

  public function setDb($db){
     // ... some code
     return $this->db = $db;
  }

  public select($name){
     return $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ...');
  }

}
```

I've tried to use `@depends setDb` annotation for `select` method but it didn't work - the `db` property is null. The only one working solution I found - call `setDb` right before testing `select` method

```
/**
 * @covers SomeClass::select
 * @depends testSetDb
 */
public function testSelect()
{
    $this->object->setDb($this->pdo);
    $actual = $this->object->select('value');
    $this->assertTrue($actual === 'something');
}
```

Looks very ugly. Any other solutions?

Comment: "Looks very ugly." could you clarify a bit why do you think so? And what goals you expect the test case to achieve?

Comment: Smart books say that one test function should contain exactly one testing subject.

Comment: well, _some_ smart books (and people) say that "...Perhaps a better rule is that we want to test a single **concept** in each test function. ...". Still, concerning your particular question `setDb()` is not part of assertion/testing, it is part of preparing your SUT, so you might consider moving it to `setUp()`, it really belong there. Secondly, I hope `SomeClass` is about db-stuff only, so you don't really want to mock PDO but to use a real one (may be on a test db, but still real one), so you don't test internal implementation of class but results it produces.

Comment: and if you care about database tests to be cheap to run, you might also consider using SQLite in-memory engine, it really makes difference

Comment: Ok moving setDb() to setUp() is a good idea. In this case I cannot probably directly test setDb() method but I can test if the database is properly loaded  in assertPreConditions() hook which is called after setUp()

Comment: And yes, I do use SQLite in-memory

Comment: I believe there's no real need to test `setDb()` directly since any test will break if you don't set it up (in `SomeClassTest`). I also think it makes more sense to verify any client that uses `SomeClass` does `setDb()` with proper argument (i mean somewhere in `AnotherClassThatUsesSomeClassTest`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * @test
 */
 public function blaTest() {
       $pdo = $this->prophesize(PDO::class);
       $this->object->setDb($pdo->reveal());

       $pdo
           ->query('SELECT * FROM something')
           ->shouldBeCalled()
           ->willReturn('test works');
       self::assertEquals(
            'test works',
            $this->object->select('something')
        );
```

This way you test the setter while injecting a mock to test the db-call in the select-method.

Comment: How does this differ from my approach? blaTest still uses setDb as a dependency which is not cool

Comment: But setDb is not the dependency. The object in db is. So setDb is a valid and rather good approach to deoendency injection. Another possibility is to inject the dependency in the constructor. That procedure is supported by many DI-Containers for automatic dependenc injection. So in short: the setDb-method is good and valid if you care about testing. Otherwise there would be no way to aboid outside dependencies in your test.

Comment: "So in short: the setDb-method is good and valid if you care about testing" That's what I wanted to hear, thanks